# Can't access aws EC2 public ip by browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a dockerized application in EC2 , which is running fine

[image]

And I have a security policy like following

[image]

Here my instance's details

[image]

If I hit https://54.167.118.150/ or http://54.167.118.150/ or https://54.167.118.150:8080 or http://54.167.118.150:8080

It shows connection refused.

But when I hit the IP in browser , it was saying refused to connect .

Comment: " hit the IP in browser" its not specific? Exactly how did you "hit" the IP? Using https, http, what port, full url?

Comment: Does your app work when you `curl` it from inside? Also, have you modfied any Network ACLs?

Comment: Curl is working from inside , I haven't modified anything in Network ACLs

Answer (score 0):

Check your Dockerfile is port 8080 is exposed or not. The port 8080 should be exposed to the host, add below line in the bottom of Dockerfile;

**EXPOSE 8080**